# "App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone" when installing APKs on Android 14

Tags: applications, updates, installation, apk, android-14

I have an APK of [Unlimited Call Log 3.1.1](https://apkhome.io/unlimited-call-log-3-1-1/), but I am unable to install it on Samsung Galaxy S24+ running Android 14. When I tried to install it, an error comes:

> App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone.

Can anyone help to solve this issue or upgrade to new Android level?

Comment: Note that the link may describe the app, but the download doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

The app is very old and therefore most likely uses a `targetSDK` value that is no longer allowed on Android 14:

### Android 14 blocks Apps developed for Android 5 and before

Android 14 has introduced a new security restriction that disallows apps that have a `targetSDK` of 23 or lower (app that have been developed for Android prior to Android 6).

> Starting with Android 14, apps with a targetSdkVersion lower than 23 can't be installed. Requiring apps to meet these minimum target API level requirements improves security and privacy for users.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#minimum-target-api-level

That means if you want to continue to use the app you need an updated version with an increased `targetSDK` version. In addition this may require additional changes to the code of the app as restrictions may apply if the targetSDK is increased.

### Modifying targetSDK value

I don't know if the app you use would require code changes. If it is just the targetSDK, then you could try to decompile the app using apktool, set the targetSDK to 23, recompile it, zipalign and apksign it. The modified APK should be installable on Android 14, however if it still works I don't know. But you can try it yourself.

Comment: The app's web page says it's for Android 4.0.3 upwards, so the targetSDK hypothesis looks very plausible.

Comment: I use apk editor and edit manifest.xml and .yml and there i change target sdk from 19 to 34, but still problem not solved and showing same error not compatible.  Can any developer download apk and make this compatible.  I no knowledge of programming at all.

Comment: @Lifeline There are other reasons why the app is not compatible. For example recent Android devices are pure 64bit devices (armv64-v8a). As the app is so old it may contain 32bit (armv7-a) code. Install the app via `adb install` and you will get a meaningful error message describing why the app can not be installed.

Comment: @robert thanks for reply and guidance.  Today i email developer and request to upgrade app and make compatible to android 14. Let's see what they does. Still did not get any reply.  They last updated 2019. Lets see...

Answer (score 10):

You may be able to sideload the apk with

```
adb install --bypass-low-target-sdk-block "apk-path"
```

This is from an [Android developer page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#minimum-target-api-level), I have not tried it. But it might give you a clearer error message.

Comment: Not sure if really a new adb version is necessary. It seems that adb simply passes the install options to `pm` which is executed on the device.

Comment: @Robert: OK, removed.