# Cannot install APK on Android 14 because of compatibility issues

Tags: apk, android-13, compatibility, android-14

I have an old APK (the app is internal and subject to an NDA) that can be installed and functions properly on Android 13. It continues to work if I install it on Android 13 and then upgrade the phone to Android 14, indicating that the app is indeed compatible with Android 14.

However, when I attempt to install it directly on Android 14, I receive a message stating, "This app was built for an older version of Android and doesn't include the latest privacy protections" (first image).

After selecting "Install anyway," I encounter an error message: "App not installed as the app isn't compatible with your phone" (second image).

Disabling Play Protect does not resolve the issue.
The option to install from unknown sources is enabled.
And I've already tried to set target SDK version to 33 and 34 - does not help.

I have no sources of it, but can extract APK and edit files (i.e., manifest) using APK Editor.

What can I change in APK so app can be installed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate question of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/256364/2241. You can try to install the app from a connected PC using adb from Android SDK as shown here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/256366/2241